# How to separate records in log file by blank line? Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I try to make my log file more readable so I want to separate records in my log file by a blank line after every application run. I use `log4j`.

I understand that the easiest way is to append `%m%n` to a single record in code. But I'm interested in doing it via configuration file.

So the question is what I have to add to configuration file `log4j.xml`?

Here is the context of my `log4j.xml` configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
        >


    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <param name="file" value="logs/logs.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806378/log4j-not-adding-newlines-between-logfile-entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another Logger defined in your configuration that uses the same settings except its `ConversionPattern` which will contain only `%n`. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <param name="file" value="logs/logs.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <param name="file" value="logs/logs.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.company.MyClass">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file2"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Then, when your app starts:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(com.company.MyClass.class);
logger.info(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve and why, but if you want an empty line between each log entry, you just have to add an extra `%n` at the end of your ConversionPattern:

```
<param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n%n"/>
```

(`%n` means "new line")

Comment: actually i want to have a blank line between logs of different application runs. what you advised me to do is not what i need. thanks though

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. You may want to look at the other answer I just made then :)